# WordPress 404 and page redirection is totally wrong

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have a page, site.com/case - which works 100%, except... all the links try to go to URL www.site.com/case/actual_page

Also I made a new page, "aboutus", and the only way to access it is via `site.com/case/aboutus`.

So I seem to somehow put all sites behind site.com/case, which is quite wrong. I would love to get rid of the `/case/` part.

So I would just have www.site.com and then sub pages such as `www.site.com/case` and `site.com/aboutus`, etc..

My .htaccess is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Also I have `page.php`:

```
<?php /* Template Name: CustomPageT1 */ ?>

<?php
 get_header();?>

<?php
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        the_content();
    endwhile;
?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

And function.php, which is just empty file at this point.

Permalinks are set to Post name.

It also seems "aboutus" page directs all the links to `site.com/case/aboutus/page_name`, when it should just go to `site.com/page_name`.

Links in "aboutus" page are all written as href="page_name.php". Why is it directing like this?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it turns out you can't use relative links in WordPress...

I changed all my hrefs from `href="pagename.php"` to `href="../pagename.php"`.

And this is working perfectly.